# XGBoost training time seems to be too long

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, training-data

I am trying to train an XGBoost classifier in Python using the xgboost package. I am using the defaults on all the parameters for the classifier and my training set has around 16,000 elements and 180,000 features for each element. I am not using the gpu to train the model, but still, the training process has taken more than five hours and is still going. I have 32GB of RAM and a 6 core Intel I7. I am wondering if this is normal time for training this classifier with the amount of data I have because I have heard of people training the model in a couple of minutes.

Comment: It seems like the library offers some parallel programming functionality which must be enabled, have you done so?

Comment: @AMC . Thank you for the response. I have set the nthread parameter to -1 so that all available cores are used during training. I'm not sure if this is what you meant but even with all cores being used, it is super slow. I don't know if this is helpful but my memory usage is at 99% during training.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, is there any way you could try running your program on a small subset of the data? That way you can figure out whether the program is just slow or if it is bugged/hanging.

Comment: @AMC . Sure. I have tried training the models with a subset of 50 and 100 samples. Each takes about 40 and 80 seconds, respectively. I have done the math and the entire training set should only take 4 hours at most, however it has not ended even after five hours

Comment: _I have done the math_ What math? That's good though, at least we can be quite certain that the program isn't broken.

Comment: For the math, since 50 samples takes 40 seconds, each sample takes 0.8 seconds. 0.8 * 16,000 = 12800. 12,800 seconds is around 3.5 hours

Comment: Do you have any way of monitoring the program? Can you confirm that it is making progress?

Comment: After letting the model run for about 7 hours, it finally completed. There were no errors during the training phase; however, the long training time might be a problem with the package or my computer. For anyone else who has this issue, I have also had a very long training time, but the training did finish

Comment: Glad to know the program was working correctly! I hope you find a way to improve the performance :)

Answer (score 3):

If training time is concern then one can switch the tree growing policy `tree_method` to `hist` which is histogram based method. With GPU it should be set to `gpu_hist`. You can find more details about its xgboost implementation here http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02754

This is the secret sauce which leads to super fast training without much compromise in the solution quality. In fact GPU based training and even lightGBM etc relies on histogram based techniques for faster training and subsequently iterations/experiments which matters a lot in time constrained kaggle type competitions. `hist` may cut training time to half or less and `gpu_hist` on gpu may take it to minutes.

PS: I would suggest to reduce the dimensionality of your data (16k X 180k) by removing correlated/rank-correlated features which will further improve not only your training time but also model performance.